# Install Linux Kernel without APT

Tags: linux, debian, grub2

I recently tried to install Debian, however apparently the small USB installation over network has a bug where it can't complete installation of the Kernel. Thus I see the grub shell when I boot.

I believe I succeeded in installing APT. However I cannot use it from the grub shell. Is it possible to install the correct Kernel from the grub shell, or move it to the target file system with only access to the Grub shell?

I know how to select the correct kernel from grub but not how to download one.

Comment: You can ty setting up a tftp server, http://wiki.osdev.org/GRUB#Load_your_kernel_over_network_.28TFTP.29 But I think your life would be much easier if you just burnt a USB stick and installed from that.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Do you mean burn the CD installation version to a USB instead , or just the Kernel ?

Comment: I mean the whole installation image, the iso file.